# How to compress a video file in android?

Tags: android, video, compression

i have list of video files in my sdcard.when i click the selected video in gridview,i want to compress the selected video file in android.How to compress a video file in android.is there any sample code availavble?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution for video compression is using `ffmpeg` library.
Here you can find a sample android app that used that library:

https://github.com/umeshbsa/ffmpeg-video-compresion-with-progress-android

another lovely library is `silicompressor` you can find that here:

https://github.com/Tourenathan-G5organisation/SiliCompressor

Answer (score 0):

Video Compression can be done by MediaCodec (From JB) and FFMPEG. Please refer documents of FFMPEG for more information on compression.

### Refer:

[ffmpeg: compress video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010832/ffmpeg-compress-video)

https://www.virag.si/2012/01/web-video-encoding-tutorial-with-ffmpeg-0-9/

Comment: refer this http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-android-applications-based-on-ffmpeg-by-an-example/

Comment: Hi Addison, download ffmpeg4android library and demo client from link http://androidwarzone.blogspot.com/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html. 

Sample contains example for compression and rotation, we can change the command to include for compression alone.

Comment: The API 18 `MediaMuxer` class may be useful.  Some sample code exercising `MediaCodec` and `MediaMuxer` can be found here: http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/